# Can't read the received firebase message in React Native Android app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to React Native development. I have integrated the firebase with my React Native app by referring to https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm . When I send the push notification from Firebase console then I am able to see the notification in my device. But I want to save it in my React Native app using AsyncStorage. So I have altered the code like

```
    componentDidMount() {
        // iOS: show permission prompt for the first call. later just check permission in user settings
        // Android: check permission in user settings

        FCM.requestPermissions()
       .then(()=>console.log('granted'))
       .catch(()=>console.log('notification permission rejected'));

       FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
         console.log(token)
         // store fcm token in your server
       });

      this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
         // optional, do some component related stuff
       });

        // initial notification contains the notification that launchs the app. If user launchs app by clicking banner, the banner notification info will be here rather than through FCM.on event
        // sometimes Android kills activity when app goes to background, and when resume it broadcasts notification before JS is run. You can use FCM.getInitialNotification() to capture those missed events.
        // initial notification will be triggered all the time even when open app by icon so send some action identifier when you send notification

      FCM.getInitialNotification().then(notif => {
   console.log(notif)
          AsyncStorage.setItem('lastNotification', JSON.stringify(notif));
         alert('hello'+JSON.stringify(notif)+' Title='+notif.title+' Body='+notif.body);
     });
   }
```

In FCM.getInitialNotification() method I am trying to store the received message. But from the alert in the same method I came to know that the received message format is something different then I expected. Alert content looks like this[image]

Please guide me to make it correct. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Well that looks ok. Please supply a picture how you want to have it looked instead.

Comment: As I am using firebase console to send message I am simply entering the notification content there and sending it. So in my React native app how can I read that. For example if I send "Hello" then in my alert I should be able to show the same .